# Map Json using jackson ObjectMapper to java object, getting error

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have below json string, i would like to read that into the java object, i am getting below error

**JSON**

```
{"models":[{"id":6002,"publisherName":"AbacusT","active":false}]}
```

Parsing in java

```
Publisher publisher = new ObjectMapper().readValue( " {\"models\":[{\"id\":6002,\"publisherName\":\"AbacusT\",\"active\":false}]}", Publisher.class);
```

**Error**

```
21:21:24,878 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/wad].[springMain]] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) Servlet.service() for servlet springMain threw exception: org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "models" (Class com.guthyrenker.wad.core.model.lookup.PublisherLookupItem), not marked as ignorable
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@418bd56d; line: 1, column: 12] (through reference chain: com.guthyrenker.wad.core.model.lookup.PublisherLookupItem["models"])
```

Code

```
// Java class
public class Publisher {



    private Integer id;


    private String publisherName;


    private boolean active;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPublisherName() {
        return publisherName;
    }

    public void setPublisherName(String publisherName) {
        this.publisherName = publisherName;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you trying to parse that json?

Comment: Publisher publisher = new ObjectMapper().readValue(
    " {\"models\":[{\"id\":6002,\"publisherName\":\"AbacusT\",\"active\":false}]}",
    Publisher.class);

Comment: Please edit that into your question. The stack trace mentions `PublisherLookupItem`. What is that?

Comment: That is same class as "Publisher" and "PublisherLookupItem" are same, for making it smaller, i have put that.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Publisher` type has no `models` property. There is therefore no way to map the root entry named `models` from the JSON. What you need is a POJO which maps to the given JSON.

If we format it, we get

```
{
    "models": [
        {
            "id": 6002,
            "publisherName": "AbacusT",
            "active": false
        }
    ]
}
```

The root object has an entry called `models` which is a JSON array. That array contains a single JSON object. The JSON object has three entries which map to your `Publisher` POJO. So you need a containing POJO with a single field of some collection type (or an array) of `Publisher`.

Something like

```
public class PublisherModels {
    private List<Publisher> models;
    // getters and setters
}
```

Then use your `ObjectMapper` with this class instead of `Publisher`.

```
PublisherModels publisherModels = new ObjectMapper().readValue( " {\"models\":[{\"id\":6002,\"publisherName\":\"AbacusT\",\"active\":false}]}", PublisherModels.class);
```

If you're going to make `PublisherModels` generic, you'll have to use a type token (look that up on your favorite search engine). Jackson has implemented `TypeReference` for that purpose

```
new TypeReference<PublisherModels<PublisherLookupItem>>() {};
```

You can pass that object to the `ObjectMapper#readValue(..)` method.

Comment: Hi,Getting below exception, when i try above.  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.guthyrenker.wad.core.model.lookup.PublisherLookupItem
 at com.guthyrenker.wad.webui.model.Test.main(Test.java:18)

Comment: try {
   PublisherModels<PublisherLookupItem> publisherModels = new ObjectMapper().readValue( " {\"models\":[{\"id\":6002,\"publisherName\":\"AbacusT\",\"active\":false}]}", PublisherModels.class);
   List<PublisherLookupItem> list = publisherModels.getModels();
   PublisherLookupItem publisherLookupItem = list.get(0);
   System.out.println(publisherLookupItem.getPublisherName());
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

Comment: @user3157090 Please don't put code in comments. Edit it into your question. You didn't try what I suggested. You added generics. If you're going to try and deserialize into a generic type, you're going to have to use a `TypeReference`. See my edit.